# knife ssh - jetty will stops suddenly

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, jetty, chef-infra

I have a chef infrastructure with chef-server/chef-client. I want to restart jetty from all machines using knife ssh.

There is a very strange behavior. When the jetty starts, it receive a kill signal and it stops. This is happening only when I'm using knife ssh.

```
2015-06-25 17:37:29.171:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@673b21af{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-06-25 17:37:29.171:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @17901ms
2015-06-25 17:37:31.302:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-1: Stopped ServerConnector@673b21af{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-06-25 17:37:31.303:INFO:/:Thread-1: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Thu Jun 25 17:37:29 CEST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2015-06-25 17:37:31.307:INFO:/:Thread-1: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jun 25 17:37:20 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO : org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
INFO : org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService
2015-06-25 17:37:31.509:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-1: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@675e8fe2{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-root.war-_-any-6087241756199243276.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/idm/root.war}
```

the command used to restart jetty is:

```
knife ssh -x root "name:*" "sh /opt/jetty/jetty-current/bin/jetty.sh start"
```

As I said above, if I execute the command from ssh, manually on each machine(without using knife), jetty starts and works fine. What something else `knife ssh` does instead of make a ssh on each machine and runs that command?

I've tried to fix this different ways including using & at command / creating another shell script that executes the command, but without any success.

[Here](http://paste2.org/4YfBI64w) is a paste2 with jetty.sh

There is something that kills jetty when I start it using knife. Have any idea what?

Edit: tried to put jetty.sh into /etc/init.d/jetty and start as a service with `service jetty start`, but there is the same result.

Comment: Could it be the `kill` on line 130? Perhaps try a debug print if it is executed or run with `-x`.

Comment: I've debugged into, wasn't the kill from line 130. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround which I used to solve the problem.

The thing is that knife ssh once finish execution, will kill every spawned process. Maybe there is a bug with this.

I've created a cookbook and inside it a recipe where I run `service jetty restart`. Then, using knife ssh I only execute this recipe from chef-client.